# 401 Error while Uploading image to OCR Microsoft Vision API

Tags: ios, objective-c, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am learning objective-C and I am trying to upload an image to [microsoft vision api](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc)

I have used these as headers

```
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"{*************}" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"];
```

and i am getting this message from the server

```
{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." }
```

I have tried regenerating the key and am pretty sure i am using the right key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the curly braces, specifically:

```
[request addValue:@"*************" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"];
```

Comment: I was able to resolve that error but now i am getting resource not found message. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: This means the URL is incorrect in some way.  What URL did you use?